# Getting ✖ fatal undefined after Nuxt.js runs builder.build(): how to find out what's undefined / show a full error message?

Tags: nuxt.js

When I run `npm run dev` it runs through but I get:

> ✖ fatal undefined

How can I find out what's undefined? Looks like consola.fatal is called somewhere between https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/dev/packages/builder/src/builder.js#L165 and #L186

Comment: Do u have a reproduction for this behaviour? It would be great so it can be fixed then :)

Comment: Yes. But as of right now I fixed the problems in the code so it doesn't show anymore. Now it's just about getting it to display more info so that the next time one can see right away what needs to be fixed.

Comment: create an issue in nuxt github if u can reproduce it